# I want my image to take up complete space of the bootstrap column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a layout in which I have divided row in 2 columns and want the second column which has the featured image to take up complete space of the column. I want this to work in responsive manner.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250X250">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 title">
                    <h3>first title here</h3>
                    <h2>Sub-title goes here</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <ul class="col-md-12 main-list">
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="small-images">
                <img class="small-image1" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
                <img class="small-image2" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 featured-image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300X300">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using an image which is `300*300` that is why it is taking up less space otherwise your layout is fine. I have provided a full width image it is working fine in the below snippet.
2. To make the layout responsive add different classes to the `<div>s` eg.`col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6`. Also add `class="img-responsive"` to your img tag to make the image responsive.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
          <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250X250" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 title">
                    <h3>first title here</h3>
                    <h2>Sub-title goes here</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 main-list">
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                        <li>abcdefgh ijkl mnop 1234 564 xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="small-images">
                <img class="small-image1" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-responsive">
                <img class="small-image2" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 featured-image ">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/15/46/dog-1210559_960_720.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: thanks for this response. But for small devices this is not working. I want the content image and title to be adjacent to each other and featured image to be hidden. Also the main list is not spreading out to full 12 columns. I have used hidden-sm for featured image but i think somehow its place is still occupied and the other elements are not fitting in there